# How to Create Variable Replacement for ruby on rails inside text area or editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this dilemma on how to add variable replace inside text area in rails I know you can use it via model but I need to implement it inside the new views or in the form similar to this[image: Variable Replace]

Comment: You cant do it in ruby, you have todo with JavaScript. Post yr textarea forms

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "test"
order_id = 1
order_status = "shipped"
puts "Hi #{name}, Your order #{order_id} is now #{order_status}!"
```

Comment: can i use this inside text-area?

Comment: yes. just wrap the output to a variable and output it in the textarea

Comment: I just check its working over console but not when I'm trying to implement in the text area

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/radon1284/e6121017ddf4b8a1feb92e1518a0bffd